# Why does while loop clear a variable?

Tags: c, linux, loops, gcc, scanf

I'm using gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) along with this program:

```
int main(){
    double buffer;
    double *vec = NULL;
    int dim = 0;
    char end;

    printf("ej: (1.5 2 3.7).\tVector: ");
    scanf(" %*[()]");
    do{
        vec = (double *) realloc(vec, (dim+1) * sizeof(double));
        scanf(" %lf", &buffer);
        vec[dim++] = buffer;
    }while (!scanf(" %1[)]", &end));
    //<- Here dim returns to 0
    printf("\n\t( ");
    for (int componente=0; componente<dim; componente++)
        printf("%6.2lf", vec[componente]);
    printf(" )\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `dim` variable returns to 0 (but exists --at least `gdb` stands so). The only way to keep its value alive is to declare it static.

I've also tried to compile without optimization.

Am I missing something about C? Shouldn't it stay alive?

Comment: What are your compile options? I've compiled your code with the same gcc version and dim is not zero after the first loop.

Comment: I guess `scanf(" %1[)]", &end)` is exceeding the bounds of `end` (remember that strings in C are NUL-terminated) and overwrites the next variable in memory, being `dim` (because stacks are typically 'hanging'). Try: `char end[2];` or `char end[99];` or whatever is sufficient here.

Comment: The scanf is definitely overwriting it.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Linux C". There are compilers on Linux that may support several C standards, and sometimes flavours of their own. And there are Linux specific system calls. However your program doesn't use any of them.

Comment: Please provide a _minimal_ input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The problem is certainly in `scanf(" %1[)]", &end)`; note that writing out of bounds of an array causes undefined behavior, so anything could happen including the appearance of correct execution-- it is important to be careful with array bounds to avoid UB in C.

Comment: If suddenly variables unexpected change their value, this very often dues to the code messing up the memory, (at least) then [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) is your friend.

Comment: Each time variables change "magically", your first thought should be: _buffer overflow_ and _array indexes out of range_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ruud Helderman said reading just one char via

> scanf(" %1[)]", &end)

doesn't mean it's not a string (and therefore null terminated). So I went, obviously, into a buffer overflow.

Thanks all